# PHP Database Class Not Working

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to allow the user to reorder rows in mySQL table by moving them up or down. I have 2 pages to allow this to work. It is not working and I honestly have no idea where to go from here. I am getting this error: `Fatal error: Call to undefined method Database::GetAll() in /home/www/thetotempole.ca/phptester/moveupdown.php on line 35` and here is my php:

moveupdown.php

```
<?php 

class Database extends mysqli {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct("","","","");
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            throw new Exception(mysqli_connect_error(),   
            mysqli_connect_errno());
        } 
    } 
}

include 'connect.php'; 
$db = new Database(); 

if(isset($_POST['do'])){ 

    extract($_POST); 
    //determine what direction in relation to $_POST['position'] 
    $otherpos = $do=='⇑'? $position-1:$position+1; 
    //get the two ID that should change order place 
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM employees WHERE emp_id=$position"; 
    $posid = $db->GetRow($sql); 
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM employees WHERE emp_id=$otherpos"; 
    $other = $db->GetRow($sql); 
    //change place for those two 
    $sql = "UPDATE employees SET position=$otherpos WHERE id=$posid->id"; 
    $db->Query($sql); 
    $sql = "UPDATE forums SET position=$position WHERE id=$other->id"; 
    $db->Query($sql); 

}else{ 
    // make sure all forums positions are numbered 1,2,3,4,5 etc. 
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM employee ORDER BY position"; 
    $forums = $db->GetAll($sql); 
    foreach($forums AS $f){ 
        $items[] = $f->id;     
    } 
    foreach($items AS $k=>$id){ 
        $k++; 
        $sql = "UPDATE employee SET position=$k WHERE id=$id"; 
        $db->Query($sql); 
    } 
} 

//get the number of forums to display 
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS max FROM employee"; 
$pos = $db->GetRow($sql); 
//get them by order of position 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM employee ORDER BY position"; 
$forums = $db->GetAll($sql); 

//display with up/down arrows for each 
//except first forum has only down-arrow 
//and last forum has only up-arrow 
$out ='<table>'."\n"; 
foreach($forums as $f){ 
    $out .= '<form method="post">'; 
    $out .= '<input type="hidden" name="position" value="'.$f->position.'">'."\n".'<tr>'; 
    if($f->position != 1) 
        $out .= '<td><input type="submit" name="do" value="⇑"></td>';  //up 
    else $out .= '<td></td>'; 
    if($f->position != $pos->max) 
        $out .= '<td><input type="submit" name="do" value="⇓"></td>';  //down 
    else $out .= '<td></td>'; 
    $out .= '<td>'.$f->name.'</td></tr>'."\n"; 
    $out .= '</form>'."\n"; 
} 
$out .= '</table>'; 
echo $out; 

?>
```

connect.php

```
<?
//the example of MySQL database connection
//connect.php
$continued = mysql_connect("","","","");
if ($continued) {
    echo ("Connection is succeed");
} else {
    echo ("Connection is fail");
}
?>
```

Comment: And `not working` means?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Database::GetAll() in /home/www/thetotempole.ca/phptester/moveupdown.php on line 35 is my error. I am not really sure what that means.

Comment: Ok where do we have a method `GetAll()` defined in either your class or in `mysqli` ?

Comment: $forums = $db->GetAll($sql); is in my php, I'm not really sure where else it would be.

Comment: That's where you are *calling* it, where are you *defining* it?

Comment: I'm not, how would I go about defining it?

Comment: Don't. Use a standarized method such as `fetch()` instead.

Comment: So change ' $forums = $db->GetAll($sql); ' ' to $forums = $db->fetch($sql); '?

 EDIT: I tried ' $forums = $db->fetch($sql); ' and now I'm getting the error " Fatal error: Call to undefined method Database::fetch() in /home/www/thetotempole.ca/phptester/moveupdown.php on line 35 "

Comment: So find out what method you should be using in MySQLi - the PHP docs will help there: http://php.net/mysqli. You probably need `prepare`, since your current approach has a SQL injection vulnerability. Avoid `extract($_POST)` completely - it is most unsafe `:)`

Comment: Why have you written a wrapper around `mysqli`? You're adding a lot of complexity where it's not required and you're also making some serious mistakes. When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **Avoid** using string interpolation to accomplish this. [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) can be extremely damaging.

Comment: It is a very simple web page so I don't midn having string interpolation. I got the wrapper from a different code, as said before I am fairly new to PHP/MySQL. I am just looking for a GetAll method.

Answer (score 1):

It means there is no GetAll method in the Database class or the method signature is different. In this case, I don't see any of those methods in the mysqli class. Check the [docs of the mysqli class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) for valid methods.

Since you extend your `Database` class (unnecessarily btw as other commenters mentioned, you could just use `new mysqli()`) from the `mysqli` class, you inherit all methods of mysqli, which are listed at the link above. Among them there is a `query` method that is used to send your SQL query to the server. So that part of your code should look like something like (I'm not checking your logic here, just replacing the database-related stuff):

```
$db = new Database(); 

if(isset($_POST['do'])) { 
   ...
} else { 
   // make sure all forums positions are numbered 1,2,3,4,5 etc. 
   $sql = "SELECT id FROM employee ORDER BY position"; 
   $forums = $db->query($sql); 
   foreach($forums AS $f){ 
       $items[] = $f->id;     
   } 
   foreach($items AS $k=>$id){ 
      $k++; 
      $sql = "UPDATE employee SET position=$k WHERE id=$id"; 
      $db->query($sql); 
   }
```

}

Comment: I tried searching in your link, and I didn't see any methods. I am fairly new to PHP, I'm sorry. Is there any way I could add the method into my $db class?

Comment: Addes some details to my answer, but you will need some tutorial on object-oriented programming basics, like [this one](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php-for-beginners--net-12762).